# getting a value from mysql db and post it to php page 

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

i have a little problem while getting a value from database and post it to another page , heres my code . on search.php the user enter the price min and price max , then on page result.php it shows from database the name and price of the product and a link for more infos .(info.php) this 3rd page will show some additional informations based on the Id of the product shown on result.php
i tried to hide the value of Id_product from result and post it to 3rd form but doesnt work.i got an error Notice: Undefined index: id in info.php line 4

```
//////search.php /////

<form  method="post" action="result.php" > 
<tr> <INPUT type=text size=20 name=pricemin ><BR>  </tr>  
<tr> <INPUT type=text size=20 name=pricemax ><BR>  </tr>
<tr> <input type="submit" class="Nom" id="button" value="Valider" /></tr></form>

///////result.php //////

<?php include 'includes/connection.php';
$pricemin = $_POST['pricemin'];
$pricemax = $_POST['pricemax'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM product where price between '$pricemin' and '$pricemax'";
$result = mysql_query($query);?>
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>   
<?php echo $products['name_product'] ;echo $products['price_product'] ;
echo "<a href='http://localhost/mywebsite/info.php'>More infos</a>"
?>
<form method="post" action="info.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $products['id_product']; ?>" />
</form><?php } ?>...

///// info.php //////

<?php
include 'includes/connection.php';
$id_product = $_POST['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM product where id_product='$id_product'";
$result = mysql_query($query);   ?>
<html><head><title>.. </title></head><body>
<?php 
while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
<h1>Product ID : <?php echo  $products['id_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<h1>Product name : <?php echo  $products['name_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<h1>Product Qt : <?php echo  $products['quantity_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<h1>Product Spec : <?php echo  $products['spec_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<?php } ?></body></html>
```

Comment: What is your problem?
Also are you aware that the name of your input boxes at search.php is different from the one you are calling at result.php

Comment: beside that because ive edited my code ,my problem is between result.php and info.php how can i get the id value from my database and post it to info.php . because the hidden input didnt solve my pb

Comment: im working on the answer right now. you really should clean your code here.

Comment: please , learn what spaghetti code is .. because that's what you writing

Comment: hi sir , my speciality have nothing to do with programming but i have a family to feed (some spaghetti), to keep my job i have to do this spaghetti code sir , have a nice day ! life aint easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
//////search.php /////

<form  method="post" action="result.php" > 
<tr> <INPUT type=text size=20 name=pricemin ><BR>  </tr>  
<tr> <INPUT type=text size=20 name=pricemax ><BR>  </tr>
<tr> <input type="submit" class="Nom" id="button" value="Valider" /></tr></form>

///////result.php //////

<?php include 'includes/connection.php';
$pricemin = $_POST['pricemin '];
$pricemax = $_POST['pricemax '];
$query = "SELECT * FROM product where price between '".$pricemin."' and '".$pricemax."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $products['id_product'];
echo $products['name_product'] ;echo $products['price_product'] ;
echo "<a href='info.php?id=";
echo $id;
echo "'>More infos</a>"
?>

<?php } ?>...

///// info.php //////

<?php
include 'includes/connection.php';
$id_product = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM bien where id_product= '".$id_product."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);   ?>
<html><head><title>.. </title></head><body>
<?php 
while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
<h1>Product ID : <?php echo  $products['id_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<h1>Product name : <?php echo  $products['name_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<h1>Product Qt : <?php echo  $products['quantity_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<h1>Product Spec : <?php echo  $products['spec_product'] ; ?> </h1>
<?php } ?></body></html>
```

this should pass ID to info.php

Also Form will only work if you submit a button, so if you were to click a link, form will not submit unless you use a JS onsubmit function.

Comment: Work like a magic , thats what i was looking for :) 
Thank you my friend very very much.

Comment: glad to help you. also learn to clean your code. btw if you want to pass data to another page use link instead of a form when you dont need the user to input any data but to just click.